# What's the time limit for turns in Words With Friends?

Tags: words-with-friends

When I accidentally clicked "resign" while the game was on my opponent's turn, I got this message:

> You can only resign when it is your turn.  But fear not!  If your opponent does not make a move in a reasonable amount of time they will be resigned automatically.

What is the "reasonable amount of time" referred to, here?

Comment: Whatever it is, the time limit is way way way too long. It would be nice if it could be set for each game.

Comment: @FrankTrades Really? I always think it is too short. Almost all of my games are forfeited ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [post](http://www.newtoyinc.com/wp/blog/shortened-auto-resign-times/) on Zynga's blog says that resignation times are now 11 days without a move for an invite game and 5 days without a move for a random game. (Previous times were 22 days and 7 days, respectively.)

**Update:** Based on Iszi's comments below, I've done a little more digging and found the following information about the Android version (no idea whether this applies to the iOS version as well):

> Q: Some of my games are resigning early. Why?
>
> A: This usually means the data on your app is out of sync with our server. Again, try deleting and reinstalling the app and seeing if the resigned-early games come back.

I can now confirm from personal experience that games do not always take as long as Zynga says to resign. I started an invite game at 8:59 PM Sunday local time and made no moves; when I checked Tuesday at about 10:18 AM local time, I had lost. I have my account set to update every 5 minutes, so it seems as though in this case, my game was resigned in a little over 36 hours. (I also tried deleting and reinstalling the app, and the game did not come back.)

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is.  I had two games auto-resign me, it seems, after only two days.

Comment: @Iszi, interesting ... are these random or invite games?

Comment: Random

Comment: In regards to your post about early resigning, if no moves are made whatsoever in a game, the game resigns in less than 5 days. I believe 3 days or so. Once a word is played in a game the normal time limits are enforced.